# tag-it autocomplete - codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, autocomplete

so I would like to ask why is it that my autocomplete function is not working, I want to get data from my database which is inside my controller and it's not giving me results. here are the codes.

**JS**

```
$(document).on('show.bs.modal', '#searchmusic', function() {
$('#searchtags').tagit({
    allowSpaces: true,
    placeholderText: 'Search Tags',
    autocomplete: ({
        source: function(request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: base_url + '/songtags/search_tags',
                type: "GET",
                success: function(data) {
                    var songtagdata = JSON.parse(data);
                    response($.map(songtagdata, function(key, value) {
                        return {
                            label: value.tag_name,
                            value: value.tag_name
                        }
                        console.log(songtagdata);
                    }));
                },
                error: function(request, status, error) {
                    alert(error);
                }
            })
        },
        minLength: 2
    })
});
});
```

**Controller**

```
    public function search_tags(){
    $song_tags = $this->song_tags_model->get_tags();
    $encode = json_encode($song_tags);
    echo $encode;
    }
```

Comment: are you returning `json` in response try adding `console.log(data);` and see in console that the response is not any other than `json`. although i can see you are using `json_encode()` in search_tags, also it is a valkid json or not

Comment: hmm. the problem is that. in my console.log. it doesnt display anything. guess the ajax isn't running?

Comment: it isnt showing the ajax call in network tab ?

Comment: oh. actually I'm getting data. maybe just response is coded the wrong way?

Comment: yeah thats what i am talking about , is it returning valid json string or not taht is required by tagit

Comment: also try adding  `beforeTagAdded: function(event, ui) {
        // do something special
        console.log(ui.tag);
    }` and see if it is triggered

Comment: it is actually returning a valid json.

Comment: it is returning these data.

{tag_id: "4", category_id: "2", tag_name: "Alternative", tag_date_added: "2017-10-25 16:58:14.684662", tag_date_updated: "2017-10-25 16:58:14.684662", …}
4
:
{tag_id: "5", category_id: "2", tag_name: "Rock", tag_date_added: "2017-10-25 17:12:23.018701", tag_date_updated: "2017-10-25 17:12:23.018701", …}

Comment: Hmm.., is the `beforeTagAdded` triggered ? `beforeTagAdded: function(event, ui) { // do something special console.log(ui.tag); }`

Comment: yes it's returning this data [li.tagit-choice.ui-widget-content.ui-state-default.ui-corner-all.tagit-choice-editable]

Comment: might be that its a css issue that it is appending but not showing in correct place ? remove every extra css file and see if it is populating ? just keep the one related to tagit

Comment: alright. I'll try it

Comment: still the same though

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following code example that just sets data to a fixed object:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#suggest").autocomplete({
        delay: 100,
        source: function (request, response) {
            Promise.resolve(
                [1,2,3,4,5,6]
            )
            .then(function(data){
                console.log(
                  "got data:"
                  ,JSON.stringify(
                    data,
                    undefined,
                    2
                  )
                )
                response(data);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/jquery-ui-git.js"></script>
<input type="text" placeholder="type something ..." id="suggest" />
```

If that works but the ajax version doesn't then the problem is with the request or format of the request so you'll need to update your answer with the output of the console.

You did not understand the example, here is the example applied to your code, it does not use AJAX but just sets the values according to what you are expecting your ajax to be:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#suggest").autocomplete({
        delay: 100,
        source: function (request, response) {
            Promise.resolve(
                `[{"tag_name":"helo"},{"tag_name":"world"}]`
            )
            .then(function(data){
                console.log(
                  "got data:"
                  ,data
                )
                response(
                  JSON.parse(data)
                  .map(
                    item => ({
                      label:item.tag_name
                      ,value:item.tag_name
                    })
                  )
                );
            });
        }
    });
});
```

The working example can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/32Bck/1632/). If it does not work in your page then maybe it's a css problem, if it does work then your problem is likely a xhr problem or the format of the response is not what you expected.

Comment: it's actually giving me results in the console.

Comment: @RealRich Updated my answer, it should give some results in the console, you are missing the point. The example provided is not depending on xhr so you could pretend your xhr to return any value. If the example updates your auto complete with something visible then your problem is not css but likely a xhr problem or the format of your response.

Comment: @RealRich Please read my answer carefully: `so you'll need to update your answer with the output of the console` That is the output of the console of what your xhr is returning, I know what my script is returning I wrote it. Add the console.log to your code and check what the output is